Disconnect Kafka exception is not throwing error
I am using spring Integration kafka outbount channel to send the messages to Kafka and i am using handler advice to handle the response to update status in database table (Success OR failure ).
 <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="someID"
                                        kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
                                        header-mapper="kafkaHeaderMapper"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        topic-expression="headers['topic']"
                                        partition-id-expression="headers['partition']"
                                        sync="true">
        <int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="requestHandlerAdvice"/>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain> 
<bean id="requestHandlerAdvice"
      class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
    <property name="trapException" value="true"/>
    <property name="onSuccessExpression" ref="success"/>
    <property name="successChannelName" value="successChannel"/>
    <property name="onFailureExpression" ref="failure"/>
    <property name="failureChannelName" value="failureChannel"/>
</bean>

Few times if producer is not able to send the message due to cluster is down or some other issues then it simply print WARNING in logs  and doesn't throw exception hence my app flow assume that is success and update status in table as a SUCCESS but message was never delivered.
From logs i can see the errors

WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:624 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 155018 on topic-partition xxxxxxxxxxxxx, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER

This print as WARN.
Is there any way I can catch this as as exception that we know delivery failed?
Note - I am NOT using transaction in my current flow. I was thinking if wrapping in transaction may work -- any thoughts?
Thanks

If we go to org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender, we'll see that this Got error produce response with correlation happens during retry: if (canRetry(batch, response, now)) {. And that retry in Kafka is like this: .define(RETRIES_CONFIG, Type.INT, Integer.MAX_VALUE, between(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE), Importance.HIGH, RETRIES_DOC). So, essentially infinite.

@ArtemBilan you are saying it will keep retry until Integer.MAX_VALUE ? But we have configured only 5 retries and then it simply come back as WARN, or i am missing something here?

Can you share that final WARN then? What you show right now in the question is really about that retry block in the Sender.

@ArtemBilan This is getting print in logs , i can see that in message in Sender.
WARN [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:624 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 155018 on topic-partition xxxxxxxxxxxxx, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER

(1 attempts left). - exactly what I'm talking about: warn about retry in Kafka client.

@ArtemBilan i have 3 retry &  last it print
WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:650 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition topicNmae due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker  not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now

OK. I see after that it goes to the metadata.requestUpdate(false);. So, yeah, no exception thrown from there.

@ArtemBilan how we can fix this?

I'm not fully on board with Apache Kafka internals, so might be great if you can share some simple project where we can reproduce the issue and I'll debug what is going on.
